# syntax error when taking a code from mac to linux machine

Tags: linux, bash, macos, shell, optimathsat

I have this code that I wrote to execute on my Linux remote machine for some reppetitive experiments with different input.

```
#!/bin/bash
#timeout 10m
trap "exit 1" INT 

repeat() {
  executiontime=$( /usr/bin/time  /home/me/optimathsat-1.5.1-macos-64-bit/bin/optimathsat < file.smt2 2>&1 >/dev/null)
  echo "$executiontime">>results.csv

}
export -f repeat

for length in 30 ; do
    step=0.05
    short=0 #0
    long=1
    for i in {1..10}; do
    ratio=0
        for j in {1..10}; do
                declare -a listofresults
                echo "$length $short $long $ratio">>results.csv
                python3 main.py "$length" "$short" "$long" "$ratio">file.smt2
                chmod 775 file.smt2
                declare total=0
                declare m=0
                parallel -n0 repeat ::: {1..10}
                ratio=$(echo "scale=10; ($ratio) + ($step)" | bc) 
            done
            short=$(echo "scale=10; ($short) + ($step)" | bc)
            long=$(echo "scale=10; ($long) - ($step)" | bc)
        done
    done
trap - INT
```

I have executed this code on my own mac machine and it worked (using gtime instead of /usr/bin/time ) but now I get this error which I don't know what it means/

```
   0inputs+0outputs (0major+66minor)pagefaults 0swaps
    /home/me/optimathsat-1.5.1-macos-64-bit/bin/optimathsat: 1: /home/project/optimathsat-1.5.1-macos-64-bit/bin/optimathsat:

 Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

when I try to execute the instructions manually I get this:

```
src$ python3 main.py 10 0.5 0.5 0.5>file.smt2
```

I checked file.smt2 and it is as it should be, then this happens

```
src$ /home/project/optimathsat-1.5.1-macos-64-bit/bin/optimathsat < file.smt2
    -bash: /home/project/optimathsat-1.5.1-macos-64-bit/bin/optimathsat: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with [tag:python]?

Comment: Typo: `!/bin/bash` should be `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: Could you please run the script with a trace?  That is `$ bash -x myscript.sh`.  It will show which line is causing the error.  See http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html

Comment: @Barmar yes I have it correct in my code, it's just a typo here

Comment: @Chris the main file I am running is a python file

Comment: @waffles123, please make sure to show us an accurate [mcve]. We can't be expected to guess at which errors are relevant and which aren't. Copying and pasting is best.

Comment: I think the problem is happening in the `optimathsat` program, not this script.

Answer (score 0):

- You can start with with debugging with a trace, `$ bash -x myscript.sh`. It will show which line is causing the error. See [The Linux Documentation Project's guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html).
- I always get bit that macOS is case insensitive, though it preserves case.  That is, I can `echo "Hello" > foo; cat Foo` on macOS but not on Linux.
- macOS is BSD based, not Linux based.  There are a few basic commands that have different flags between the two systems.

Hope this helps!